# Custom response always req.wantsJson

Tags: sails.js

I have a Helper, a Controller and a Custom response.

The Helper is used to create some new objects *Books*.

The Controller calls the Helper to create a new Book. If the isbn10 attribute of the Book is already used, a custom response displays a 409 error webpage to the user.

Since the REST API must be callable from the outside (e.g. mobile app), a json version of the 409 error webpage is sent if the request to the Custom response wants a JSON.

For some reason I ignore, the Custom response never redirects to the 409 webpage and always considers that the test `if (req.wantsJSON)` is `true`. The Flag 2 log is never returned.

Since I am new to Sails.js, am I missing a concept here?
**Helper :**

```
module.exports = {

  description: 'Create new Books',

  inputs: {

    name:  {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      description: 'The Books name.',
      example: 'Frida Kahlo de Rivera',
    },

    isbn10: {
      type: 'number',
      required: false,
      allowNull: true,
      description: 'ISBN10 number of the Books',
      example: 2123456802,
    },

  },


  exits: {

    isbn10AlreadyInUse: {
      description: 'This isbn10 is already used',
    },

  },


  fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
    // Build up data for the new books record and save it to the database.
    var newName = String(inputs.name);
    var newIsbn10 = Number(inputs.isbn10);

    // ISBN10 is unique?
    isIsbn10Exists = await Books.findOne()
    .where({
      isbn10: newIsbn10
    });

    if (isIsbn10Exists) {
      sails.log('Isbn10 already in use found in helper');
      throw 'isbn10AlreadyInUse';
    }

    // If no error, create Book
    await Books.create({
      name: newName,
      isbn10: newIsbn10,
    });

    sails.log('helper - new book created');
    // Since everything went ok, send our 200 response.
    return exits.success();

  }
```

**Controller**

```
module.exports = {

  description: 'Create new books',

  inputs: {

    name:  {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      description: 'The Books name',
      example: 'Frida Kahlo de Rivera',
    },

    isbn10: {
      type: 'number',
      required: false,
      allowNull: true,
      unique: true,
      description: 'ISBN10 number of the Books',
      example: 2123456802,
    },

  },


  exits: {

    success: {
      description: 'New Books was created successfully.'
    },

    fieldAlreadyInUse: {
      responseType: 'alreadyInUse',
      description: 'The provided field supposed to be unique, but is already in use'
    },

  },


  fn: async function (inputs, exits) {

    // Build up data for the new books record and save it to the database.
    var newName = String(inputs.name);
    var newIsbn10 = Number(inputs.isbn10);

    newIsbn10 = newIsbn10 || null;

    await sails.helpers.books.newBooks.with({
      name: newName,
      isbn10: newIsbn10
    })
    .intercept('isbn10AlreadyInUse', 'fieldAlreadyInUse');

    // Since everything went ok, send our 200 response.
    return exits.success();

  }

};
```

**Custom response**

```
module.exports = function alreadyInUse() {

  var req = this.req;
  var res = this.res;

  sails.log.verbose('Ran custom response: res.alreadyInUse()');

  if (req.wantsJSON) {
    sails.log('Flag 1');
    return res.sendStatus(409);

  } else {
    sails.log('Flag 2');
    return res.redirect('/409');
  }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

this.req.wantsJson is true when you make API calls.

```
// In the controller file
...
fn: async function (inputs, exits) {

  // API calls / Postman / Cloud
  sails.log.info('wantsJSON', this.req.wantsJSON); // true then 'Flag 1'

  // Browser
  sails.log.info('wantsJSON', this.req.wantsJSON); // undefined then 'Flag 2'

  // Manipulate the value for testing
  this.req.wantsJSON = false; // redirects to /409 then 'Flag 2'
...
```

If you make API calls with Postman, testing or Cloud then this value is true but if you try directly from browser i.e. a local from then this value is *undefined*.

I have tested and you could try that by including text/html headers:

```
//some.test.js

const request = require('supertest');

...

describe('Testing books', () => {
  it('should redirect when wantsJSON is false', (done) => {
          request(sails.hooks.http.app)
            .post('/books')
            .send({
              name: "A name", isbn10: "duplicated-entry"
            })
            .set('Accept', 'text/html')
            .set('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            .expect(302, done);
        });

  it('should NOT redirect when wantsJSON is true', (done) => {
          request(sails.hooks.http.app)
            .post('/books')
            .send({
              name: "A name", isbn10: "duplicated-entry"
            })
            .expect(409, done);
        });
});
```